# Huge if statement, refactor using Enum or Map?

Tags: java, enums, hashmap, refactoring

I  stumbled upon a 400 lines if/else, with about 100 clauses in it. So I feel the urge to refactor that monster.

The method is of this form:

```
private void updatePaymentField(Payment payment, String fieldName, String value) {
    if (Field.FIELD_1.equalsIgnoreCase(fieldName)) {
        payment.getField1().setId(value)

    } else if (Field.FIELDS_2.equalsIgnoreCase(fieldName)) {
        payment.setField2(valueToSet)

    } else if (Field.FIELDS_3.equalsIgnoreCase(fieldName)) {
        UtilClass::setField3(payment, value)

    } else if ... // 100 more of these

}
```

I changed that into an `enum` that takes a `String` (the field name) and a `BiConsumer<Payment, String>` (the method/lambda that will update the field on the payment)

```
enum Field {
    UNDEFINED("", null),

    FIELD1(Fields.FIELD1, (Payment, value) -> payment.getField1().setId(value)),
    FIELD2(Fields.FIELD2, Payment::setField2),
    FIELD3(Fields.FIELD3, UtilClass::setField3),
    // 100 more of these, 

    private String fieldName;
    private BiConsumer<Payment, String> populateFunction;

    Field(String fieldName, BiConsumer<Payment, String> populateFunction) {
        this.fieldName = fieldName;
        this.populateFunction = populateFunction;
    }

    public static Field getByName(String name) {
        return Arrays.stream(values())
                .filter(p -> p.getFieldName().equals(name))
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(UNDEFINED);
    }

    private String getFieldName() {
        return fieldName;
    }
    public BiConsumer<Payment, String> getPopulateFunction() {
        return populateFunction;
    }
}
```

then basically the big `if` can be replaced by

```
private void updatePaymentField(Payment payment, String fieldName, String value) {
    Field field = Field.getByName(fieldName);
    if(field != Field.UNDEFINED) {
        field.getPopulateFunction().accept(payment, value);
    }
}
```

That works and is all good, but I am thinking that I might have overdone it can achieve the same thing with a simple `Map`

```
Map<String, BiConsumer<Payment, String>> fieldMap = new HashMap<>();
fieldMap.put(Fields.FIELD1, (Payment, value) -> payment.getField1().setId(value))
fieldMap.put(Fields.FIELD2, Payment::setField2)
fieldMap.put(Fields.FIELD3, PaymentUtilClass::setField3)
// 100 more of these,
```

And use it the same way

```
private void updatePaymentField(Payment payment, String fieldName, String value) {
    BiConsumer<Payment, String> populateFunction = fieldMap.get(fieldName);
    if(populateFunction!=null) {
        populateFunction.accept(payment, value);
    }
}
```

I feel that accessing the `BiConsumer<Payment, String>` would be quicker using the `Map` than using the `getByName` method on the enum, and the `Map` notation is also lighter.
So I am thinking the `Map` might be a better choice.

So the question is: Before I change this to a `Map`, is there any objective value in using en `enum` over a `Map` in that specific use case?

Comment: The map seems obviously better, because you don't have to linearly search it for an entry.

Comment: @AndyTurner Thanks, it's also my feeling, just want to make sure I am not overlooking something.